# Java - Extending Classes

Tags: java

```
public class DefaultCalculator
{
    public Boolean isEligibleForNewProcess(Z z)
    {
         // Do Something 
    }

    public BigDecimal getY(P p, Q q)
    {
        return y;
    } 

    public BigDecimal getX(P p, Q q)
    {
        return x;
    }
}

public class ExtendedCalculator  extends DefaultCalculator
{
    public Boolean isEligibleForNewProcess(Z z)
    {
       // Do Something  diffrent 
    }
```

}

I have a factory to basically instantiate one of this .

```
public class CalculatorFactory
{

    @Autowired
    DefaultCalculator defaultCalculator;

    @Autowired
    ExtendedCalculator extendedCalculator;


    public DefaultCalculator getCalculator(Z z){
        switch (z.getType()) {
        case a:
            return defaultCalculator;
        case b: 
            return extendedCalculator;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have the calculator Factory .
I have p and q .Can I use those functions in DefaultCalculator without the object of DefaultCalculator ?
I want to use the functions getY and getX without Z .

Can i do that some how ? How should i change the design of classes ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which functions do "those functions" refer to? What do you mean you want to use getY and getX without Z? Their input doesn't depend on Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't abundandtly clear, but if I understand you correctly, you're asking can you use `DefaaultCalculator` methods from an `ExtendedCalculator`; if so, the answer is yes, public and protected methods and variables from a parent class are available in an extended class.

As long as the object you're referencing is a `DefaultCalculator` or `ExtendedCalculator` you should be able to access `getY` and `getX`.  As far as what you're talking about with `Z` I have no clue how that's relevant to what I think you're asking.

Comment: No, What I mean exactly is how can I use the methods of DefaultCalculator's  getX and getY .  All I have is CalculatorFactory object  ,p and q

Comment: Without creating an instance of DefaultCalculator, the only way I can think of is to make those methods static and call them like `DefaultCalculator.getX(p,q);`.

Comment: Can we somehow change the complete design to accomodate the need?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. But if you change the methods to `public static BigDecimal` you don't need to have an instance of `DefaultCalculator` to call those methods.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not that clear. What I understand that you have the `DefaultCalculator` with tow method `getX(P p, Q q)` and `getY(P p, Q q)` and you want to call these methods without creating new object of type `DefaultCalculator`.

Basically,  if you want to call a method with in some class you have to creat an object of that class. But you can do one of the following:

(Note: I don't know what you are trying to do, but that may helps)

1- I can see that you have the class `ExtendedCalculator`
Which extends `DefaultCalculator` so you can create object `ExtendedCalculator` and call the methods `getX(P p, Q q)`and `getY(P p, Q q)`from that object as follow:

```
ExtendedCalculator someObj=new ExtendedCalculator();
someObje.getX(someVar1,someVar2);
```

2-  you can create `static` methods and call directly by class name.